# React: How to prevent a setInterval from being delayed after a button is clicked to start it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this React Pomodoro Clock, there is a function `countDown` which starts `setInterval`, however, when the button `id="start_stop"` is clicked to start `countDown`, there is some delay before starting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
CodePen.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wozniak-kfuss

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

/*
* A simple React component
*/
const initState = {
  breakLength: 5,
  sessionLength: 25,
  init: 'session',
  stateIndex: 0,
  timeLeft: undefined,
  timeLeftSeconds: undefined,
  started: false,
  intervalFunc: undefined
}

const states = [ { name: 'session', duration: 1500 }, { name: 'break', duration: 300 } ]

const secondsToMins = (time) => {
  let converted = ('0' + Math.floor(time / 60)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + Math.floor(time % 60)).slice(-2);
  return converted;
}

class Clock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initState;
    this.breakDecrement = this.breakDecrement.bind(this);
    this.breakIncrement = this.breakIncrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionDecrement = this.sessionDecrement.bind(this);
    this.sessionIncrement = this.sessionIncrement.bind(this);
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sessionSeconds = this.state.sessionLength * 60;
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: sessionSeconds });
    this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(sessionSeconds) });
  }

  breakDecrement() {
    // decrements the breakLength and the breakSeconds
    // breakLength is only a number ie. 5 (does not show seconds)
    // breakSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength - 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  breakIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let breakLength = this.state.breakLength + 1;
    if (breakLength > 0 && breakLength < 61){
      this.setState({ breakLength: breakLength });
      let breakSeconds = breakLength * 60;
      states[1]['duration'] = breakSeconds;
    }
  }

  sessionDecrement() {
    // decrements the sessionLength and the sessionSeconds
    // sessionLength is only a number ie. 25 (does not show seconds)
    // sessionSeconds is that nunber converted into seconds
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength - 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength-1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength-1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength-1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  sessionIncrement() {
    // same as decrement except does increment
    let sessionLength = this.state.sessionLength + 1;
    if (sessionLength > 0 && sessionLength < 61){
      states[0]['duration'] = sessionLength*60;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength+1,
        timeLeftSeconds: (prevState.sessionLength+1)*60,
        timeLeft:  secondsToMins((prevState.sessionLength+1)*60)})
      );
    }
  }

  startStop(id) {
    // starts the countDown, which runs continuously until the start/stop button
    // is pressed again, which pauses the countdown.
    // the id parameter is used by countDown to play the audio beep
    if(!this.state.started){
      this.countDown(id);
      this.setState({ started: true});
    }
    // pauses the countDown
    if(this.state.started){
      let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
      clearInterval(intervalFunc);
      this.setState({ started: false});
    }
  }

  reset() {
    let intervalFunc = this.state.intervalFunc;
    clearInterval(intervalFunc);
    // reset state to default values
    this.setState({ breakLength: 5 });
    this.setState({ sessionLength: 25 });
    this.setState({ init: 'session' });
    this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: 1500})
    this.setState({ timeLeft: '25:00' });
    this.setState({ stateIndex: 0 });
    this.setState({ started: false });
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: undefined });
  }

  countDown(id){
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(() => down(this.state.timeLeftSeconds--), 1000);
    this.setState({intervalFunc: intervalFunc});

    const down = (time) =>
    {

      if(time > 0){
        // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});
        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
      }

      if (time <= 0) {

        let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
        sound.play();

        let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
        this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex});
        this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: states[stateIndex].duration});
        this.setState({ init: states[stateIndex].name});
        this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time)});

        console.log(time);
        console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
        console.log(this.state.init);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="clock">
      <h1 id="title">25-5 Clock</h1>

      <div>
      <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
      <p id="break-length">{this.state.breakLength}</p>
      <button id="break-decrement" onClick={e => this.breakDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="break-increment" onClick={e => this.breakIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <div>
      <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
      <p id="session-length">{this.state.sessionLength}</p>
      <button id="session-decrement" onClick={e => this.sessionDecrement()}> Decrease </button>
      <button id="session-increment" onClick={e => this.sessionIncrement()}> Increase </button>
      </div>

      <hr/>

      <div>
      <p id="timer-label">{this.state.init}</p>
      <p id="time-left">{this.state.timeLeft}</p>
      <button id="start_stop" onClick={e => this.startStop(e.target.id)}><audio id="beep" src='./beep.mp3'></audio> start/stop </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick={e => this.reset()}> reset </button>
      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
};

/*
* Render the above component into the div#app
*/
ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>25-5 Clock</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="app"></app>
    </main>
 </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The delay when clicked on countdown is because of the second parameter passed inside setInterval. You should call it immediately once then your interval will handle the function after the appropriate time you passed. This way you can skip delay but a delay will always be present it you use setInterval to call your function after specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

- Set interval will call down after 1s. (delay 1 second)
- you have method call method like: `down(this.state.timeLeftSeconds--)` will be first time down with current time, no change time here and then this.state.timeLeftSeconds will decrease later. (delay 1 second)

**=> You will delay 2 seconds with your code.**

My suggest is "you should call down function right away and modify way down the timeLeftSeconds"

```
descreaseCurrentSecond = () => --this.state.timeLeftSeconds;

countDown(id) {
    // set the function to a variable and set state to it, so the function
    // can be paused with clearInterval()
    var intervalFunc = setInterval(
        () => down(this.descreaseCurrentSecond()),
        1000
    );
    this.setState({ intervalFunc: intervalFunc });

    const down = (time) => {
        if (time > 0) {
            // converts seconds to MM:SS at every t-minus
            this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });
            console.log(time);
            console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
        }

        if (time <= 0) {
            let sound = document.getElementById(id).childNodes[0];
            sound.play();

            let stateIndex = (this.state.stateIndex + 1) % states.length;
            this.setState({ stateIndex: stateIndex });
            this.setState({ timeLeftSeconds: states[stateIndex].duration });
            this.setState({ init: states[stateIndex].name });
            this.setState({ timeLeft: secondsToMins(time) });

            console.log(time);
            console.log(this.state.timeLeft);
            console.log(this.state.init);
        }
    };
    
    down(this.descreaseCurrentSecond());
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! For a one second delay: `descreaseCurrentSecond = () => this.state.timeLeftSeconds--;`